# Excel 2010 paste values

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, wbREF As Workbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wbREF = Workbooks.Open("ALSP.xls")      'you may want to put the full path here

Range("B7:L61").Copy ws.Range("N7")         'copy to original sheet
wbREF.Close False

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wbREF = Workbooks.Open("FLSP.xls")      'you may want to put the full path here

Range("B7:L61").Copy ws.Range("Z7")         'copy to original sheet
wbREF.Close False

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wbREF = Workbooks.Open("GASP.xls")      'you may want to put the full path here

Range("B7:L61").Copy ws.Range("AL7")         'copy to original sheet
wbREF.Close False
```

I am now using this macro which works great.  My question is for the workbook "GASP" which has formulas in it.  This marco does not copy over the values which I need.  Can anyone suggest a work around.  Thanks

Comment: do the values not match what you see in the worksheet? Have they been calculated? What is showing on your target? Do you want to copy the formulas or the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you only really need this one line once at the top of your macro:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

Next, to copy VALUES only, you need to switch to a two-line copy/paste command:

```
Set wbREF = Workbooks.Open("GASP.xls")      'you may want to put the full path here

Range("B7:L61").Copy 
ws.Range("AL7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'copy to original sheet
wbREF.Close False
```

Comment: Does this work for you? Are you going to close out this thread?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is have the macro copy the values and not just the formulas. Check the out code below

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wbREF = Workbooks.Open("GASP.xls")

Range("B7:L61").Copy
ws.Range("AL7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbREF.Close False
```

Also make sure excel has Automatic Calculation turned on. You can check this in the "Formulas" Ribbon. One final thing to be aware of is that you need to be careful about qualifying your references. Whenever you call the "Range" function, it is wise to specify the workbook and the worksheet on which that range is contained. Like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Al7")
```

or

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     Set rng = .Range("Al7")
End With
```

Comment: +1 Good suggestion on fully qualifying the path for the worksheet/Range. But you missed it for "Range("B7:L61").Copy". Define a second variable for a worksheet and then set it to a worksheet in "GASP.xls" and then add that before Range("B7:L61") as well. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses.  Worked beautifully.